# Has the most important problem of philosophy of science been solved?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

There exists a precise criterion of what counts as valid mathematics and what doesn't. By the word precise, I mean algorithmic. There exists a known algorithm that will take as input a pair consisting of axioms, and reasoning of a mathematician written in a formal language and output valid or invalid. It is amazing that this algorithm and formal language exist, because this solved the demarcation problem of mathematics (almost) completely. If I am not mistaken about the history, I believe the origins of this work can be traced back to philosophers of mathematics Frege and Russell. Unfortunately, the analogous thing has not been accomplished in philosophy of science as far as I am aware. I am interested in knowing if there are known solutions to the problems below:

**Problem 1:** Give  a formal language  and an algorithm that takes as input a pair (Experimental data, A scientist's reasoning) and output valid or invalid.

Perhaps the goal of problem 1 is too much to hope for, here is a weaker version below

**Problem 2:** Give  a formal language and an algorithm that takes as input 2 pairs (Experimental data "E",  reasoning of scientist 1),(Experimental data "E", Reasoning of scientist 2) and the algorithm will decide which of the reasoning of the 2 scientists is more rational.

Do any philosophers of science propose solutions to any of the above 2 problems in the philosophical literature , i.e. Did any philosopher of science try to accomplish what Frege, Russell tried to accomplish  ?

**Note:** I am aware of some proposals for  solutions to the demarcation problem like naive induction, hypothetico-deductive method, Popper's falsification. My problem with all of these approaches is that they are either don't capture what scientific activity is or are  not algorithmic and so fail to give an airtight solution to the demarcation problem.

**Another note:**  when I say science in the above text, I am mostly thinking about  physics, a domain which has the most potential to be well defined and admit an algorithmic solution to its demarcation problem.

Thank you

---

**Edit:**  I set two well defined problems and asked if anyone attempted solving them in the philosophical literature. The answer I would expect is either "Yes, it had been considered before,check out this reference...", or "No, it has not been considered before". The comments I am getting so far are neither of these two options, but they instead try to persuade me that I should not be looking for an answer to these two problems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133874/discussion-on-question-by-amr-has-the-most-important-problem-of-philosophy-of-sc).

Comment: For any who are interested, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1736327/21820) is an approach that solves the problem completely. Both Solomonoff induction (SI) and AIXI fail to converge to the correct **explanation** even in simple cases like a 2/3-biased coin-flip sequence. In contrast, my approach converges to the correct explanation with probability 1. Also, my approach is clearly a **practical** solution to Problem 2, whereas SI and AIXI simply fail to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a formal ideal of empirical reasoning.

Fortunately, what you're asking for *does* exist (don't let anyone claim differently!), and it's called [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference). In Bayesian inference, we have a hypothesis H, and evidence E. Initially we assign a prior probability P(H) to H, indicating how likely we initially think H may be in the absence of evidence. Then we look at all the evidence E and update P(H) to form P(H|E), which may be read, "the updated probability of H, after learning E." P(H|E) may be calculated as follows, which is called Bayes' rule:

P(H|E) = P(H) P(E|H)/P(E)

In this formula, P(H|E) and P(H) were described already. P(E|H) is the probability of the observed evidence, *given that* the hypothesis is true. This may be calculated by following the consequences of the hypothesis. And P(E) is the prior probability of the evidence - before we've seen the evidence, what probability would we assign to seeing it?

By itself, Bayes' rule is a rigorous, mathematical property of probabilities. In theory, Bayes' rule allows one to perfectly update the probabilities one assigns to hypotheses, after seeing each additional piece of evidence.

In practice there are a few difficulties. First, how should we assign the prior probabilities P(H) and P(E)? This is often unclear or arbitrary. In many applications we try to choose P(H) and P(E) so that we are "maximally uncertain."

As an example, suppose we are trying to estimate the height of a criminal suspect, from the size of his footprints. The specific hypothesis H might be, "the suspect is between 5 ft 10 inches and 5 ft 11 inches." In this case the prior P(H) might be the fraction of the general population that does fall between those heights. E would be the measured size of the suspect's footprints, e.g. "The suspect wears a shoe size 10," and the prior P(E) could be the fraction of the general population wearing that shoe size. Then P(E|H) would be the probability that a person falls between 5'10" and 5'11", given that he wears a shoe size 10. And with these three numbers we can use Bayes' rule to find P(H|E).

However, it's not always so simple to assign the priors. For example, see the [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

A second practical problem with Bayesian inference, equally significant, is that for non-trivial examples, exact calculations tend to be computationally prohibitive. For example, performing exact Bayesian inference in a general [Bayes network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) is NP-hard.

We can, however, imagine and formally describe what empirical inference would be like if we were not limited by computation time. This is called [Solomonoff's universal theory of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomonoff%27s_theory_of_inductive_inference). It solves the problem of the priors in a rigorous way, by defining a *universal* prior.

Solomonoff induction is performed in a setting where an idealized "scientist" receives a sequence of discrete observations over time. For instance, the observations may be a video stream. The job of the scientist here is to describe the structure of the entire universe, which he can use to predict which observations will come next.

The scientist concerns himself with hypotheses represented by computer programs. Each hypothesis is a computer program that generates a sequence of observations. If the sequence of observations generated by the program happens to exactly match the observations that the scientist actually observed so far, then the hypothesis represented by the program is viable. Otherwise, the hypothesis has been ruled out.

Solomonoff's *universal prior* for the hypotheses is a distribution over all computer programs that is exponentially related to their length; longer programs have exponentially lower prior probabilities. This prior embodies Occam's razor, where simpler hypotheses are favored over more complex ones.

So, in summary, to perform Solomonoff induction, the scientist begins with a list of all possible computer programs, and to each one he assigns a probability that depends on its length according to Occam's razor. The scientist looks at his sequence of observations and "crosses out" all the computer programs that fail to output that sequence of observations. Crossing out a hypothesis, H, means to determine that P(H|E) = 0. Then the scientist normalizes the probabilities of the surviving hypotheses (multiplying all the probabilities by a constant factor so they again sum to 1.0, which probabilities must do). The scientist can then predict future observations, by looking at the sequences of observations that the surviving hypotheses predict, weighted by the probability of each surviving hypothesis.

Solomonoff's universal inference has been applied to formally describe an AI agent called [AIXI](http://www.hutter1.net/ai/uaibook.htm). In theory, AIXI is **provably the most intelligent general-purpose agent**, and the way it works can be written down in just one line of math (halfway down the link provided).

The only downside of AIXI and Solomonoff induction is that they are computationally infeasible. In fact, they are not even computable! Exact Solomonoff induction is equivalent to solving the halting problem. And in practice they cannot be implemented effectively due to computational constraints. However, they still serve well as an ideal that more practical artificial reasoners attempt to approximate.

Comment: I checked the wikipedia link for Solomonoff's theory. It seems that Solomonoff gave a mathematical proof for occam's reason, no ? Or did he just take it as an axiom ?

Comment: I was hoping that once we have a formalized notion of empirical reasoning, one can then prove a completeness theorem, just like how one can prove a completeness theorem for FOL, once one has a formalized notion of mathematical reasoning. Luckily, the wikipedia page mentions a something about the completeness theorem. Is it the same kind of completeness theorem I am thinking of ?

Comment: One more question: How does Solomonoff's theory compare to Valiant's PAC theory which Scott aranson argues that it gives a mathematical justification for Occam's razor?

Comment: @Amr Solomonoff induction takes Occam's razor as a premise, and shows how it can be implemented in math. It doesn't prove Occam's razor. To my knowledge completeness/incompleteness theorems don't apply to Solomonoff induction because it's incomputable (it is limit-computable though). Do you have a link to where Aaronson says PAC justifies Occam's razor?

Comment: Here is the link to Aranson's paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1791  , page 25 till 27

Comment: I don't understand the details of the answer fully. Solomonoff's work seems ti be interesting and I ll have to learn it someday along with PAC theory. My only trouble with attempts like these of your answer is that they ignore the predicitive sucess of a theory and focus only on the explanatory power. However, I think its a step in the right direction. Thus, I will accept your answer as it is the only sensible response I have gotten so far on this post, and it also teaches me something new: Solomonoff's work

Comment: It also seems it's not algorithmic, thus not meeting my requirement of algorithmic checking. Am I missing something ?

Comment: The question seemed to be how we formalize and/or algortithmize converting experimental data into interpretations. As much as Bayesianism is useful, it takes already formulated hypotheses and interpreted evidence as inputs, i.e. the conversion in question takes place without it. If this is supposed to illustrate how formalization is methodologically useful it is a wrong kind of illustration: we can't conceptualize the data, but hey, at least we can run some stats on it. I can think of some formal heuristics for generating hypotheses and interpretations, but Bayesianism would not be among them.

Comment: @Amr AIXI is limit-computable, and there is a variant of AIXI called AIXI-tl which is fully computable and duplicates the behavior of the most effective possible agent that uses computation time t and space l (though using exponentially more time and space itself). So it is algorithmic, though not practical to actually implement. BTW, Occam's razor can be understood from the fact that you can't have a uniform PMF over an infinite set of hypotheses - you have to order them somehow and eventually assign lower probabilities to later hypotheses in your order, or they won't sum to 1.

Comment: @Conifold The Bayesian ideal is useful in current scientific practice because it lets you say when and how the actual research methods fall short of the Bayesian ideal. To the extent they fall short, they may be improved, even though the perfect Bayesian ideal remains out of reach. For example, Bayesian inference has been proposed by many as part of a solution to the replication crisis. See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13164-018-0421-4 for one article on the subject.

Comment: @Conifold "The question seemed to be how we formalize and/or algortithmize converting experimental data into interpretations", no. The question is about how do we formalize the notion of a good scientific argument. Thus, the experimental data and the scientist's reasoning are both given as inputs as mentioned in my question. They are given as an input pair (experimental data, scientist's reasoning) . This is analogous to automated proof verification which will take as input (axiomatic system, mathematician's proof)

Comment: @Amr If the interpreted experimental data comes from the same source as the reasoning based on that interpretation the "goodness" involved is of a limited kind involved in writing good lab reports. Meaningful controversies in science come from scientists disagreeing on both elements of the pair, and the arguments there are over their different interpretations. This is why Bayesianism and other bookkeeping techniques that take them as inputs are not very relevant to comparing the quality of arguments.

Comment: @Conifold I am not sure I understand. I don't want the algorithm to take as input "interpreted experimental data" but rather take crude "experimental data", i.e. a table of measurements recorded by a collection of sensors for example.  Scientists could disagree on how to interpret the data but will not disagree that the data exists (assuming no plagiarism)

Comment: @Amr There may be a way to do it systematically, with Kolmogorov complexity. If you could produce a standardized data set summarizing all experimental observations from the field, scientists could compete to find the minimum description length. Better theories could be used to find shorter descriptions of the data. Creating a vast data set for an entire field, while avoiding the problems of P-hacking/cherry picking, could be quite difficult, though, depending on the field (easier in physics).

Comment: @Amr Right, this is what logical positivists called "protocol sentences", and the idea of disentangling them from interpreted "theoretical sentences" was thoroughly undermined back in 1950-60s, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/science-theory-observation/#Observationanddata). On how the formalist "received view" was replaced by semantic view of theory vs experiments see [Suppe, Understanding Scientific Theories: An Assessment of Developments, 1969-1998](https://www.princeton.edu/~hhalvors/teaching/phi520_f2012/Suppe_2000.pdf).